PIVPN unable to connect from client using cloudflare domain name
i have problem connecting to PiVPN but only if the connection is using domain name.
Provider: cloudflare
client: openvpn
Below are the scenario that I am able to connect to PiVPN:

Changed the .ovpn file remote address to my local raspi IP, connect to my local wifi, i am able to connect to PiVPN.
Change the .opvn file remote address to my ISP public IP address, i am able to connect to PiVPN thru my mobile network.

However, when i changed to remote address to domain name(eg: anything.mydomainname.com), the client not able to connect to the PiVPN thru mobile network.
So port forwarding is not the issue. I am not sure if it is some wrong setting in cloudflare?
In cloudflare dns records, below are the example of what i set:
Type:A
Name:anything
Content:my public ip address
Proxy status:proxied
TTL:auto
in PiVPN setup, i just put the public dns name as example: anything.mydomainname.com
I also setup ddclient. Not sure if it is relevant, but i just put here:
protocol:cloudflare
server:api.cloudflare.com/client/v4
login: cloudflare account
password:password of cloudflare account
zone:mydomainname.com    \r\n
anything.mydomainname.com
Any suggestions are greatly appreaciated.
Thanks in advance!!!

I found some workaround, but i think it will comporise security.
I turn off the proxy status in cloudflare to dns only and i am able to connect PiVPN now
